# How to access the second argument from the last command in the history ?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history, history-expansion

I am starting to learn some Regex, therefore I use this command repeatedly:

```
grep pattern /usr/share/dict/american-english
```

Only the part with pattern changes, so I have to write the long expression "**/usr/share/dict/american-english**" again and again.

Someone made the remark that it is possible to expand an argument of a command from the command history by typing cryptic character combinations instead of the full expression. 
Could you tell me those cryptic character combinations ?

Comment: Is this about the second argument or the last argument?

Comment: in this very case the last argument happens to be the second, I did not make this distinction clear.

Comment: In that case, the `bash`, `dash`, `zsh`, `mksh`, and `ksh` shells *(at least, that I know about)* will all recognize the `$_` last arg special parameter *(some do so only in interactive mode, though)*. It just expands like a variable: `grep somepattern filename; grep otherpattern "$_"`. You can usually see its contents in the output of `set`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `<M-.>` (or `<Esc>.` if your Meta key is being used for something else), that is, Meta-dot (or <esc> dot), where Meta is usually the Alt key, to recall the last argument of the previous command. So, first you would type

```
$ grep foo /usr/share/dict/american-english
```

And then if you wanted to grep for something else, you would type

```
$ grep bar
```

After typing a space and then <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> (that is, first pressing the escape key, and then the period key):

```
$ grep bar /usr/share/dict/american-english
```

You can also use either of the following:

```
$ grep bar !:2
$ grep bar !$
```

Where `!:2` and `!$` mean "second argument" and "last argument" respectively.

Comment: This is for bash and shells that use readline using emacs (default) bindings: with `editing-mode vi` set you need to add a binding to `~/.inputrc` for `yank-last-arg` and for Zsh you need to bind `insert-last-word`...

Comment: @jasonwryan, if it's the last arg you want, then in any of *(interactive)* `zsh`, `bash`, `ksh`, `mksh`, or `dash` shells you can just use `$_`. POSIXLY that binding is already set, though, to `ESC _` when `set -o vi` is in effect.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks Mike, I must have rebound it for compatability...

Comment: @jasonwryan - no problem - this just happens to be the only shell keyboard trick I know - I suck at remembering/configuring all of those quick-type shortcuts. If you don't mind, compatibility w/ what? Is there some program you use that does it differently? Oh, I can also remember ESC @letter for the `_letter` alias binding - but only because I still can't figure out how to make it work w/ bsd `editline`.

Comment: @mikeserv I bind it that way so that it is the same no matter whether I am using Bash or Zsh (both in vi mode) or on a machine with Bash in Emacs mode (it is one of the bindings I really hammer).

Answer (score 2):

In general (with Bash)  `<Esc> N <Esc> .` will recall the N'th argument from the previous command into the current command line (where N is 0-based).

For the second argument from the last command, that would be:

`<Esc> 1 <Esc> .`

If you wanted the third argument, then

`<Esc> 2 <Esc> .`

... and so on.

As others have mentioned, if you want the **last** argument from the previous command, there's a specific shortcut for that in just:

`<Esc> .`